# Proof of non-zero set if $ \lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

How would I go about proving that, for any real $ n \times n $ matrix, for the set

$ W = \lbrace \textbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid (A-\lambda I)^2 \textbf{w} = \textbf{0} \rbrace $,

$ W \neq \lbrace  \textbf{0} \rbrace $ if and only if $ \lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Honestly I have no idea where to start with this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $|A-\lambda I|^2 = 0 \iff |A-\lambda I|=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $A$ has eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then there exists an eigenvector $x \ne 0$ such that $(A-\lambda I )x = 0$ so in particular also $(A-\lambda I )^2x = 0$ so $x \in W$.

Conversely, if $W \ne \{0\}$ then there is some $x \ne 0$ such that $(A-\lambda I )^2x = 0$. In particular, the matrix $(A-\lambda I )^2$ is not invertible. Then $A-\lambda I$ also cannot be invertible since a product of two invertible matrices is invertible. Thus there is some $y \ne 0$ such that $(A-\lambda I)y = 0$, and hence $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Am I right in saying that we know $ (A-\lambda I)^2 $ is not invertible because its product with $ x $ is the zero vector?

Comment: @jharri Yes, a matrix $B$ is not invertible if and only if there exists a nonzero vector $x$ such that $Bx = 0$. We used this fact twice in the above proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

- For the implication, if $\lambda $ is not an eigenvalue, then $A-\lambda I$ is invertible.
- For the converse, notice that $$\ker(A-\lambda I)\subset \ker\big((A-\lambda I)^2\big).$$